# Exception handling for memmove_s() function in C++

Tags: c++, c, exception

I am in a situation where I'm using `memmove_s()` to copy a buffer in a safer way.
So, at first, I just used the `memmove_s()` and I tested when destination size is greater than the source size and thrown an exception. Then, I put it inside a `try/catch` and it didn't catch the exception. The reason is that I am using a C code inside a C++ code. So, I found a Microsoft solution using `__try/__except` block. However, I got the error `Cannot use __try in functions that require object unwinding`.
That's a part of my code:

```
int filter(unsigned int code, struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS* ep)
{
    puts("in filter.");
    if (code == ERANGE)
    {
        cout << "_DestinationSize >= _SourceSize" << endl;
        return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
    }
    else
    {
        cout <<  "didn't catch the exception, unexpected." << endl;
        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
    };
}

string GetValue()
{
    return string("Value");
}

extern "C" void get_str_value(string src, char* dest, unsigned int destSize)
{
        __try
        {
            auto r = memmove_s((void*)dest, destSize + 1, src.c_str(), src.size() + 1);
            cout << "r=" << r << endl;
        }
        __except (filter(GetExceptionCode(), GetExceptionInformation()))
        {
            std::cout << "Exception" << std::endl;
        }
}
```

So, is there any way to solve that problem?

Comment: Wrong kind of exception. `memmove_s` is not a C++ function and doesn't throw exceptions that C++ can catch. `memmove_s`'s default behaviour is to abort the program and force you to fix a buggy program. You can change what the handler does to something kinder and gentler, but you're better off writing a program where you check that the call is safe  ahead of time and not call `memmove` if it isn't.

Comment: Any reason you just don't compare `src.size` against `destSize` and if `destSize` is too small, then throw an exception?

Comment: The object that needs unwinding is very likely the source string `src`. Have you tried passing it not by value but by (constant) reference? Like in `std::string const& src`?

Comment: What makes you think that `memmove_s()` is safer (than `memmove()`, I suppose)?  There are reasons that most programmers who are not beholden to Microsoft ignore all those *_s functions.  Don't buy into the hype.

Comment: Side note: You may be able to use [`std::string::data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) to get access to the array inside the string and save yourself having to copy.

Comment: I'm also curious about why you need this `get_str_value` function in the first place? What problem is it supposed to solve that calling `src.c_str()` directly wont solve (if a pointer to a C-style null-terminated string is needed)?

Comment: hi @user4581301, thanks for your reply. I was trying to use it because I was trying to find a function that checks everything for me so that I don't need to put all the checks inside my function. Cannot use data() because doesn't guarantee null-terminated string.

Comment: @NathanOliver, the reason is that I was trying to find a function that does that for me. Apparently `memmove_s()` is not the case.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, it's because this is a C code implemented inside a C++ code. I just need the function signature in C-style. Cannot use string in C.

Comment: If it is relevant that you cannot use `string` in C, then how does it make sense that you use it as the type of one of your function's arguments?

Comment: The buffer in a `std::string` is guaranteed to be null terminated since C++11, but definitely disregard my advice if you're compiling to the older standards.

Comment: *I am in a situation where I'm using `memmove_s()` to copy a buffer in a safer way.*  Safer?  Not really.  [Read this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm).  And then [read this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1106.txt).  And if you're using the Microsoft implementation: "...the implementation is incomplete and conforms neither to C11 nor to the original TR 24731-1...the Microsoft implementation cannot be considered conforming or portable"